# javaFX передача данных из TableView в TextField

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Хочу реализовать кнопку редактирование, данных из `TableView` (`getSelectedItem`) должны передаваться в другую форму в `TextField`. При запуске получаю:

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
```

Контроллер:

```
public class ControllerMain implements Initializable {
    static ObservableList<UserData> data;
    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;
    @FXML
    public TableView<UserData> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column1;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, Integer> column2;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column3;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column4;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try (Connection con = new DBConnect().getConnected();
             ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT  * FROM job.job")) {
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            while (rs.next()) {
                data.add(new UserData(rs.getString("company_name"), rs.getInt("phone"), rs.getString("address"), rs.getString("other")));
            }
            String companyName = "companyName";
            column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, String>(companyName));
            String phone = "phone";
            column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, Integer>(phone));
            String address = "address";
            column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, String>(address));
            String other = "other";
            column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, String>(other));
            table.setId("cell-style");
            table.setItems(null);
            table.setItems(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void openUpdateForm() {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/updateForm.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
            stage.setTitle("Редактирование");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка открытия формы редактивания: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

И другой контроллер окна редактирования:

```
    public class ControllerUpdateData implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private  TextField txt2;
    @FXML
    private TextField txt3;
    @FXML
    private TextField txt4;
    @FXML
    public TextField txt1;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        txt1.setText(new ControllerMain().table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().companyNameProperty().getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У FXMLLoader есть метод getController:

```
...
private void openUpdateForm(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/updateForm.fxml"));
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        // получаем экземпляр контроллера
        ControllerUpdateData controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        // передаем ему выделенный элемент
        controller.setUserData(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());


        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNIFIED);
        stage.setTitle("Редактирование");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Ошибка открытия формы редактивания: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ControllerUpdateData {
...
    public void setUserData(UserData selectedItem) {
        // обновляем UI
        txt1.setText(selectedItem.companyNameProperty().getValue());
        // или
        txt1.textProperty().bindBidirectional(selectedItem.companyNameProperty());
    }
...
}
```